# How to find integers in a text file?

Tags: python, integer, text-files

Sorry, I am new. Maybe it is silly but,

```
C:\\Users\\derw\\Documents\\tt_EngPC_11\\tt\\MSIXP64\\bin\\tt.1:3549:    scfwb  979 contact node pairs not converged

C:\\Users\\derw\\Documents\\tt_EngPC_11\\tt\\MSIXP64\\bin\\tt.1:3593:    scfwb  293 contact node pairs not converged

C:\\Users\\derw\\Documents\\tt_EngPC_11\\tt\\MSIXP64\\bin\\tt.1:3637:    scfwb  207 contact node pairs not converged

C:\\Users\\derw\\Documents\\tt_EngPC_11\\tt\\MSIXP64\\bin\\tt.1:3681:    scfwb  147 contact node pairs not converged

C:\\Users\\derw\\Documents\\tt_EngPC_11\\tt\\MSIXP64\\bin\\tt.1:3725:    scfwb  97 contact node pairs not converged

C:\\Users\\derw\\Documents\\tt_EngPC_11\\tt\\MSIXP64\\bin\\tt.1:3769:    scfwb  61 contact node pairs not converged

C:\\Users\\derw\\Documents\\tt_EngPC_11\\tt\\MSIXP64\\bin\\tt.1:3813:    scfwb  17 contact node pairs not converged

C:\\Users\\derw\\Documents\\tt_EngPC_11\\tt\\MSIXP64\\bin\\tt.1:3857:    scfwb  9 contact node pairs not converged

C:\\Users\\derw\\Documents\\tt_EngPC_11\\tt\\MSIXP64\\bin\\tt.1:3901:    scfwb  3 contact node pairs not converged

C:\\Users\\derw\\Documents\\tt_EngPC_11\\tt\\MSIXP64\\bin\\tt.1:3945:    scfwb  1 contact node pair not converged

C:\\Users\\derw\\Documents\\tt_EngPC_11\\tt\\MSIXP64\\bin\\tt.1:3969:    scfwb  All contact node pairs converged

C:\\Users\\derw\\Documents\\tt_EngPC_11\\tt\\MSIXP64\\bin\\tt.1:4073:    scfwb  123 contact node pairs not converged
```

This is an example from my text file. And it continues like this.

I want to select only the numbers in this text file such as 979,293,207,147... And import it in a dataframe or list (I am not sure which I have to use to make a graph). Can someone help me for this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: You probably mean numbers surrounded by spaces (or tabs ?), as there are other numbers in the file. Consider the regular expression `" [0-9]+ "`.

Answer (score 3):

Using regular matching, it will get the number between two spaces

```
import re

result = []
with open ("your_file_path", "r") as f:
    for info in f:
        pattern = r"[\s]*([\d]+)[\s]"
        num = re.findall(pattern, info)
        result.extend(num)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['979', '293', '207', '147', '97', '61', '17', '9', '3', '1', '123']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` to split lines to make a list. Then pick the 3rd element by `list[2]`.

A simple example:

```
str = "C:\\Users\\derw\\Documents\\tt_EngPC_11\\tt\\MSIXP64\\bin\\tt.1:4073:    scfwb  123 contact node pairs not converged"
stx = str.split()
print(stx[2])
>> 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a text file like

```
filename = "name.txt"
numbers = []
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers.append([int(n) for n in line.strip().split('')])
```

Comment: Welcome to answering on stack**overflow**. Example lines have been given: try processing those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this while reading each line from the text file:

```
'''
Read the file using readlines() object and then loop in for each line to 
perform the below operation.
'''
import re
print(re.findall(f"scfwb ([\w-]+$)",line))
```

And then instead of printing, save it any data-type format you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions `findall()`  for getting the numeric data from the each line and append it to a list. Then, flatten out the list using list comprehension and convert them to integers(if needed) using `map()` function.

Final output will be in a list.

**Code:**

```
import re
filename = r'...\Data\file1.txt'
temp =[]
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        temp.append(re.findall(r'[\s]\d+[\s]', line))

temp = [ x for y in temp for x in y ]
numbers = list(map(int,temp ))

print(numbers)
```

**Output**:

```
    [979, 293, 207, 147, 97, 61, 17, 9, 3, 1, 123]
```

Comment: How about `temp += re.findall(…)`?